# Postman not reaching AWS EKS API endpoint

Tags: node.js, docker, postman, amazon-eks, amazon-ecr

I'm trying to figure out how to get postman to work with EKS. I have a simple nodejs app.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();


app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('hello world'));

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('My REST API running on port 3000!');
});
```

Here's everything I've done so far:

I created a docker container and successfully pushed it to ECR.
Also I tested docker by running it locally and I was able to reach it and get `hello world` response so the docker container seems fine.

I created an EKS cluster with the docker container and have the api server endpoint

[image]

but when I try and make a call with postman, I get

[image]

I even tried adding access key and secret from IAM user that has access to EKS, but I get same error.

When I configured the cluster, I set it to public so I don't understand why Postman can't reach the API endpoint.
[image]

Also I added the following permissions to the IAM user I'm using in postman.  I wasn't sure which one was correct so I added all of them. I also put the security credentials for that IAM user in postman.

[image]

What am I missing? I appreciate the help!

Comment: did you configure role and binding? eksworkshop.com/beginner/090_rbac/create_role_and_binding

Comment: In the first image in my question, I have my role there. if I go into it, then I have the permission there. I believe this is what you're talking about, but I could be wrong https://postimg.cc/bDSCwByN

Answer (score -1):

Actually, your Postman is reaching AWS EKS API endpoint, but you are getting authentication/authorization error - `403 Forbidden`. I see `OpenID Connect provider URL` in the API config, so I would expect OIDC authentication and not AccessKey/SecretKey. Check AWS EKS documentation or contact your AWS support.

Comment: I haven't been able to find any documentation on how to use OIDC with postman in AWS and AWS support requires me to pay a subscription so that is not ideal. I've searched google, but haven't seen any examples. If you could provide a more detailed explanation on how to use postman with AWS EKS, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: @user6680 unfortunately, that is out of the scope the original question. Especially when you didn't provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example - RBAC configuration, roles configurations, .... are missing.

Comment: I've documented everything that I've done so far in detail with pictures. The IAM/RBAC is the default one that is created when you create a cluster: https://postimg.cc/w1QQfvRn There's no more I can document because I don't know what else to do which is why I asked the question. If you can show me how to resolve this with instructions/screenshots of configuring postman to hit EKS api successfully without 403 error, I'd appreciate it. The bounty is clear. Second to last sentence says ```What is the problem and how can I solve it?``` so this isn't outside the scope of the question